# How to get Flask/Gunicorn to handle concurrent requests for the same Route?

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

**tl;dr** A method decorated with `route` can't handle concurrent requests while Flask is served behind a gunicorn started with multiple workers and threads, while two different methods handle concurrent requests fine. Why is this the case, and how can the same route be served concurrently?

---

I have this simple flask app:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
import time
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/foo')
def foo():
    time.sleep(5)
    return jsonify({'success': True}), 200

@app.route('/bar')
def bar():
    time.sleep(5)
    return jsonify({'success': False}), 200
```

If I run this via:

```
gunicorn test:app -w 1 --threads 1
```

If I quickly open up `/bar` and `/foo` in two different tabs in a browser, whichever tab I hit enter on first will load in 5 seconds, and the second tab will load in 10 seconds. This makes sense because gunicorn is running one worker with one thread.

If I run this via either:

```
gunicorn test:app -w 1 --threads 2
gunicorn test:app -w 2 --threads 1
```

In this case, opening up `/foo` and `/bar` in two different tabs both take 5 seconds. This makes sense, because gunicorn is running either 1 worker with two threads, or two workers with one thread each, and can serve up the two routes at the same time.

**However, If I open up two `/foo` at the same time, regardless of the gunicorn configuration, the second tab will always take 10 seconds.**

How can I get the same method decorated by `route` to serve concurrent requests?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This problem is probably not caused by Gunicorn or Flask but by the browser.
I just tried to reproduce it. With two Firefox tabs it works; but if I run two `curl` processes in different consoles then they get served as expected (in parallel), and their requests are handled by different workers - this can be checked by enabling `--log-level DEBUG` while starting gunicorn.

I think this is because Firefox (and maybe other browsers) open a single connection to the server for each URL; and when you open one page on two tabs, their requests are sent through the same (kept-alive) connection and as a result come to the same worker.

As a result, even using async worker like `eventlet` will not help: async worker may handle multiple *connections* at a time, but when two requests land on the same connection then they will necessarily be handled one-by-one.

Comment: Interesting that originally such browser's behaviour regarding connections is intended to *speed up* loading by avoiding extra overhead of establishing new connections. But in this situation (with slow handling on server side) we see that it can result in slowing things down.

Comment: I just tried with one tab in Chrome and one tab in Firefox and received the expected results. Thanks and nice call.